# Entering another Schengen Country from India on EU / EAA Residence Permit

Tags: schengen, eu

I am a non-EU national (Indian) currently staying in Norway. I hold a valid Norwegian Residence Card for family members of EU nationals.

I am aware this allows me access to travel, visit and enter various Schengen countries.

My question is - Can I travel and enter another Schengen state (Lithuania) directly when travelling from India while holding a Norwegian Residence Card?

Or do I need Norway as a first point of entry into Schengen and then travel to Lithuania?

Will I face any issues by immigration / airline authorities in Lithuania or elsewhere?

Comment: Are there direct flights from India to Lithuania?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I travel and enter another Schengen state (Lithuania) directly when travelling from India while holding a Norwegian Residence Card?

Yes. You can enter the Schengen area at any port of entry.

> Or do I need Norway as a first point of entry into Schengen and then travel to Lithuania?

No.  You can enter the Schengen area at any port of entry.

> Will I face any issues by immigration / airline authorities in Lithuania or elsewhere?

You should not have any problems on this account.